# load parse text from file

Tags: jquery, parsing

Hi I am trying to load a html file as a string, find the img src attributes and then load those into a cycle slider.  cycle-slideshow is expecting a full  tag, not just the href.
I am new to jQuery and been stuck for a while.  Suggestions? Thanks.

JQUERY

```
function loadImages (stringData) {
var $img = $stringData.find('img')
    .each(function() {
        $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('add',$(this).html());  
    });
}

$.get("BooranRd01.html",loadImages);
```

HTML

```
<ul>
<li><img src="img/BooranRd01/img01.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="img/BooranRd01/img02.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="img/BooranRd01/img03.jpg"></li>
</ul>
<div class="projdesc">
Booran Road Reserve is to be described here.
</div>
<div class="projtags">
public, render
</div>
```

Comment: you don't need `$` for your variables

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadImages (stringData) {
    $('img').each(function() {
        $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('add',$(this).attr('src'));  
    });
}
```

probably will work

Comment: I tried this but no cigar function loadImages (stringData) {
    $('img').each(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('src'));  
    });
}

Comment: `$.get("BooranRd01.html",function(data){loadImages(data)});`

Comment: I tried that and still no luck.  Thanks for your help Sam

Comment: I have now tried to work with find(), html() and parseHTML() and seem to be getting more lost.  Any more help appreciated

Comment: no i have it in `$(document).on("click",#booranlink,function(){...)`